# Writing inline assembly for Windows API in C

Tags: c, winapi, assembly

I am trying to figure out how to start learning assembly, specifically inline assembly inside C programs, but I have realized that there are various different syntaxes and manners of writing this language. Things which in C will create minimal difference, such as the choice between Code::Blocks and Visual Studio, seem to have a great impact when deciding to learn the assembly language.

What I've found is that gcc uses syntax such as the following, to write assembly inside of a C program:

```
__asm__(
"movl\n"
);
```

However, my goal is to interact with Windows, and write Windows API related functions in assembly, which, according to MS documentation, uses syntax such as the following:

```
__declspec(naked) MyAssembly(void) {
    __asm {
          mov
    }
}
```

The first syntax compiles when I run it on Code::Blocks, however I cannot get the second snippet to run on Visual Studio, and it is unclear if I lack some sort of dependency, or maybe an extension.

Is there any library or extension for assembly required? Or can I simply define an `__asm` block and start writing assembly in it?

Comment: What is the reason for writing any code in assembly in Windows?

Comment: It is specifically what I require. I'd like my C programs to use inline assembly, however I started assembly today so a bit confused on what programs to use.

Comment: So you do need it at all. If you are learning assembly better write the assembler files and use proper assembler instead of inline assembly. The inline assembly has a specific purpose and syntax related to the purpose. Read https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=msvc-170 Read the **whole** documentation - not only one invalid example.

Comment: On Windows you have the added complication that inline assembly doesn't work for 64-bit programs. And writing 32-bit assembly seems a bit like last millennium. Also, in your specific example, `mov` just says that something is to be moved, but it is missing info about what and where to move it.

Comment: Oh, and Visual Studio contains an assembler for compiling separate .asm files (no extensions required). That works for both 32- and 64-bit mode, just not for inline assembly.

Comment: inline asm doesn't involve any libraries.  Either your compiler supports it or it doesn't.  (Although `clang -fasm-blocks` to handle `asm { }` syntax like MSVC uses isn't on by default; normally clang only allows GNU C inline asm with a template string.)

Comment: Simply adding .asm files to a C or C++ project in Visual Studio is probably the most convenient way to get started (and take full advantage of MASM, specifically the *"macro"* part). [MASM for x64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe) explains how to do that.